# Panda runtime warning Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects

Tags: python, pandas, computational-finance

I am currently working on homework 2 for the coursera computational finance.

While executing this line:

```
ep.eventprofiler(df_events, d_data, i_lookback=20, i_lookforward=20,
            s_filename=report_filename, b_market_neutral=True, b_errorbars=True,
            s_market_sym='SPY')
```

I get the error:

```
anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py:2397: RuntimeWarning: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
```

Which creates the pdf file, shows the number of events occurred but not actually draw the events. I am not sure why this occurs. I am using pandas **0.18.0**

Any ideas? I appreciate the help.

df_events.dtypes sample:

```
ALTR    float64
ALXN    float64
AMAT    float64
AMD     float64
AMGN    float64
AMP     float64
AMT     float64
         ...
WDC     float64
WEC     float64
WFC     float64
WFM     float64
WHR     float64
WIN     float64
WLP     float64
WM      float64
WMB     float64
WMT     float64
XLNX    float64
XOM     float64
XRAY    float64
XRX     float64
XYL     float64
YHOO    float64
YUM     float64
ZION    float64
ZMH     float64
SPY     float64
dtype: object
```

Here is the d_data.dtypes log sample:

```
           YHOO    YUM   ZION    ZMH     SPY
2008-01-02 16:00:00  23.72  37.88  45.29  66.29  144.93
2008-01-03 16:00:00  23.84  37.35  44.38  66.36  144.86
2008-01-04 16:00:00  23.16  36.82  42.40  66.50  141.31
2008-01-07 16:00:00  23.18  37.68  43.28  68.66  141.19
```

I get

```
 d_data.dtypes
*** AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dtypes'
```

when I try to print out the d_data dtypes.

Comment: It looks like `dtype` of some column in some `DataFrame` is not `datetime`, but `string`. What is `print df_events.dtypes` ? And if `d_data` is `DataFrame`, `print d_data.dtypes` ?

Comment: Can you add sample of datas and dtypes?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the question with the log samples. Event profile takes a matrix so having d_data as dict shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: Thanks, what is `df_events.index` ? Is it `DatetimeIndex` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the trouble is caused by the line:

```
df_rets = df_rets - df_rets[s_market_sym]
```

in these couple of lines:

```
if b_market_neutral == True:
    df_rets = df_rets - df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_events[s_market_sym]
```

in `eventprofiler(...)` function. Quite frankly I think the line is a bug and it should be put as a comment, to say at least - as the logic behind escapes my understanding. Others are just fine.

If you set the argument `b_market_neutral` to `False`, it will give you a nice graph, but that also takes into account the SPY market data when calculating the mean return. So the workaround, in order to use a "proper" logic when calculating mean values, would be to comment this line and recompile QSTK with this modification.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

@DanielTC thanks for pointing out where the issue was, I can confirm it.

i think the logic is that market returns should be subtracted from the individual 
stocks daily returns, so you are left with just what the stock gained/lost

I solved it like this:

```
if b_market_neutral is True:
    # it fails here: df_rets = df_rets - df_rets[s_market_sym]
    df_rets = df_rets.sub(df_rets[s_market_sym].values, axis=0) # this works
    del df_rets[s_market_sym]
    del df_events[s_market_sym]
```

Answer (score 1):

@Atti, you are right.

```
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame 

Expression df - df['A'] is deprecated after pandas release 0.15.2
```

---

```
Warning
df - df['A']
is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release. The preferred way to replicate this behavior is df.sub(df['A'], axis=0)
```